# Other language support in Sphinx speech recognizer

Tags: multilingual, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am analyzing [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4) speech recognizer for one of our project. Requirement is to covert speech to text with support for 6 languages including English (US). Does someone have any idea whether this is possible in Sphinx or not?

The reason we have chosen Sphinx is that we want the application compatible with Windows, Mac and Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Sphinx is very flexible. All you need, is a proper learning file for each language (and that's probably the most difficult part).

Comment: From where I can get the Learning file for each language? Are these already available for popular languages like Spanish, French, German etc ?